# How can I get Search API to index flags from flag.module

Tags: 7, flags, search

As far as I can tell by [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1315850), the Flag module should be visible to the [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) module, so I should be able to add it for indexing somehow, but I can't figure out how.

It is not present in the list of fields when editing the Search API index, nor in the “Add related fields” dropdown below. Any pointers?

Comment: Which version of the Flag module are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be a caching issue or something similar. After reinstalling, the Flag was available in the Search API interface.